# Dplyr ~ select something, except

Tags: r, exception, filter, dplyr

So I have the following code:

```
library (dplyr)
dataset1 <- filter(dataset0, dataset0$type == "black" | dataset0$type == "orange")
```

What this code does is to add in dataset1 every row of dataset0 that has type = "black" or type = "orange".

What if I want to take everything else EXCEPT orange and black. Is the following correct?

```
library (dplyr)
dataset1 <- filter(dataset0, dataset0$type != "black" | dataset0$type != "orange")
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method could be be:

```
 dataset1 <- filter(dataset0, !(dataset0$type == "black" | dataset0$type == "orange") )
```

Your suggestion is incorrect. When you negate a compound expression you need to change the OR's to AND's if you dont negate the entire expression.

```
dataset1 <- filter(dataset0, dataset0$type != "black" & dataset0$type != "orange")
```

This has nothing to do with dplyr in particular. It's just basic logic. I also suspect that you should not be including the dataframe name with the "$" operator in your logical expressions. Try:

```
dataset1 <- filter(dataset0, !(type == "black" | type == "orange") )
```

Comment: Tried the above but they don't seem to work properly. Maybe it is because about changing the "or" to an "and" as it is mentioned in the bellow comment ~ I am not sure though. :/

The result I receive is weird  there are some cells that have been removed but I do not understand which.

Comment: The logic I offered delivers the correct resutls in a small example. I don't know why you are getting unusual results. You need to post an example that demonstrates what you are seeing. I suggest using dput() to construct examples since that has the greatest chance of delivering a reproducible example.

Comment: It worked! I don't understand why, but I tried:

dataset1 <- filter(dataset0, !(type == "black"))
dataset1 <- filter(dataset1, !(type == "orange"))

I don't know why it does not provide me the result I want in one line code :/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the 'or' to an 'and', like so

First, make some fake data

```
type <- c(rep("black", 5), rep("orange", 5), rep("green", 5))
dataset0 <- as.data.frame(type)
```

Now subset using `&` in your logical statement

```
dataset1 <- filter(dataset0, dataset0$type != "black" & dataset0$type != "orange")
```

If you don't change the `|` to `&`, you'll get back the original data frame (with orange and black both included), like so:

```
dataset1 <- filter(dataset0, dataset0$type != "black" | dataset0$type != "orange")
dataset1
     type
1   black
2   black
3   black
4   black
5   black
6  orange
7  orange
8  orange
9  orange
10 orange
11  green
12  green
13  green
14  green
15  green
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment. 
I do not quite understand the usage of the type that you mention. I mean, I do not know the exact amount of "blacks" and "oranges" I just want them to be removed (judging by the number next to them and the data frame that you have provided, it is a sum of them, right?)

I do understand what you do in the last two lines but I do not understand the purpose of the first line and I would kindly ask for an explanation if possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the first two lines just set up some fake data, so that you can see the effect of using | or & in the filtering statement. The filter statement will work no matter how many records there are, but since you hadn't provided data, I made some up to test the two different filter statements.